# How do I sort a list by data attribute ignoring a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, sorting

I've got an unordered list that I want to sort. All the list items have a data attribute `data-index` with their corresponding list index number. I want to order the list according to this index number, however, I want to ignore the list item that has the class `.active`

So in my following structure I'm trying to return all the list items after the one with the class active in the order of their `data-index`. The list item with class `.active` should be ignored and stay on top.

```
<ul>
    <li class="active" data-index="8">Item 8</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="6">Item 6</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="5">Item 5</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="4">Item 4</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="7">Item 7</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="9">Item 9</li>
</ul>
```

How would I go about doing this?

I've included a jsfiddle with my basic structure.

http://jsfiddle.net/T9qQt/6/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#sortList').click(function(){
   $('ul .inactive').sort(function(a,b) {
     return $(a).data('index') > $(b).data('index');
}).appendTo('ul');
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V8r5c/)

Comment: a sort needs to return -1,1, or 0, your sort will only return true or false (1 or 0)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$('#sortList').click(function () {
   var $active  = $('.active');
    var els = $active.nextAll().sort(function(e1, e2){
        return +$(e1).data('index') - +$(e2).data('index');
    }).insertAfter($active);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8e2rK/)

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job,

```
$('#sortList').click(function () {
    $("ul li.inactive").sort(function (a, b) {
        return +$(a).data('index') - +$(b).data('index');
    }).appendTo($("ul"));
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eBBzp/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="8">Item 8</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="6">Item 6</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="5">Item 5</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="3">Item 3</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="4">Item 4</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="2">Item 2</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="1">Item 1</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="7">Item 7</li>
    <li class="inactive" data-index="9">Item 9</li>
</ul>

<button id="sortList">Sort this list</button>


$('#sortList').click(function(){
    $('.inactive').sort(function(x,y) {
        return $(x).data('index') - $(y).data('index');
    }).appendTo($('.inactive').parent());
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/puvanarajan/T9qQt/11/)